# return largest phone number in JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, replace, phone-number

I have to return the largest phone number,not index, from an array in Javascript. I am trying to remove the non digit characters then find largest number. I am new and not experienced with the syntax. Alot of examples show parts of my problem. I don't know how to connect them into one function and how to return the answer. Please help me out. Heres what I have:

```
function myFunction(array) {
    var largest = array.replace(/\D/g, '');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (largest < array[i]) {
            largest = array[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(largest);
}

myFunction([509 - 111 - 1111, 509 - 222 - 2222, 509 - 333 - 3333]);
```

Comment: 509 - 111 - 1111 is not a number. If it is a string you should surround it with "509 - 111 - 1111"

Comment: What do you mean by "largest phone number"? The phone number with the largest digit? The phone number whose parts sum to the largest total?

Comment: @DanielMendoza see the commment of @K Ф

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is an alternative.*

I'd recommend to keep each part of the number in an array (making them an **integer**).

```
function myFunction(array){
    var res="";
    for(var i=0,l=array.length;l>l;i++){
         res=res+array[i][0]+' - '+array[i][1]+' - '+array[i][2]+'\n'
    }
    console.log(res)
}

myFunction([[509,111,1111],[509,222,2222],[509,333,3333]]);
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I found a way that works though. I would think this approach might not work if you had , say, 100 numbers or 20 even. and its missing a few things. Thanks for sending it though.

Comment: @DanielMendoza If you need to use this with multiple numbers, you can do another loop inside of that and go adding each part of itself in the string `res`. Hope this be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by fellow friends, you need to wrap the phone numbers within quotes as they are not numbers. Once you have done that, try following logic to extract the desired results for you

```
function myFunction(array) {

  // Creates the number array against the telephone numbers 
  var numberArray = array.map(function(phone){
     return parseInt(phone.replace(/\D/g, ''));
  });


  // Now it is simple to compare and find the largest in an array of numbers
  var largestIndex = 0;
  var largestNumber = numberArray[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
     if (largestNumber < numberArray[i]) {
        largestNumber = numberArray[i];
        largestIndex = i;
     }
  }
  // Fetch the value against the largest index from the phone numbers array
  console.log(array[largestIndex]);
}

myFunction(["509 - 111 - 1111", "509 - 222 - 2222", "509 - 333 - 3333", "509 - 333 - 3332"]);
```

Comment: thankyou for your insight. I had added .map to my function after what I had and the quotes. I didn't use parseInt though. That was the missing link. Before that I was getting the right number returned ,but in the wrong format. ParseInt returned the phone number back to its original format after adding .replace. Well in a quick explanation anyways. Thanks again, this showed me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to pass the numbers as strings, as K phi suggested:

```
myFunction(["509-111-1111", "509-222-2222", "509-333-3333"]);
```

First, you'll want to remove the dashes from the string. You can do this with the `replace` method, which takes a character to search for, and a character to replace it with. For `replace` to match all instances of the dash, we need to use a regular expression, with the `g` flag which means "global". We're finding a dash and replacing it with nothing, which amounts to deleting the dashes. In this case, you'll do this:

```
"509-111-1111".replace(/-/g,'');
=>"5091111111"
```

You'll then need to turn the strings into `Number`s, if you want to compare or add them. You can do this with `parseInt(string,radix)`. `radix` defines what base to use: in this case you'll use base ten. So your `parseInt` call will look like this:

```
parseInt("5091111111",10); 
=> 5091111111
```

You can perform this process on each string in the arguments, and then compare them to determine the largest one:

```
var numbers = [];
for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    var numberString = array[i].replace(/-/g,'');
    var number = parseInt(numberString,10);
    numbers[i] = number;
}
var largestNumber = numbers[0];
for (var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > largestNumber) {
         largestNumber = numbers[i];
    }
}
return largestNumber;
```

Comment: `"509-111-1111".replace('-','');` would only replace the first occurrence. You would have to do something like `"509-111-1111".replace(/-/g,'');` to replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some built in JavaScript functions then you can use the [map method of arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to modify each element of the array, and the [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) method to find the largest number.

```
function myFunction(array) {
    var array = array.map(function(elementOfArrayAtIndex) {
        return parseInt(elementOfArrayAtIndex.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
    });
    var largest = Math.max.apply(null, array);
    console.log(largest);
}

myFunction(["509 - 111 - 1111", "509 - 222 - 2222", "509 - 333 - 3333"]);
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v3b7gx6L/1/

This is basically what the map method is doing

```
for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
  array[j] = array[j].replace(/\D/g, '');  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am just going over this again for , i don't know why!, and I am not sure what the ,10 is on the third line. My first thought is to apply it to the ten integers in each index?

Comment: @DanielMendoza It's the second argument to the parseInt function. It tells  parseInt the radix of the integer you are parsing basically the radix defines what base the number is in like base 10, base 2, etc... In older browsers it is required to signify base 10, because it is not the default and does something unexpected without it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Well I was way off! haha thanks for sharing the knowledge